# Two Dimensional Array: C Programming

Tags: c, arrays, dimensional

Can anyone help, I am stuck on solving this question:

> Write a function in C that takes three parameters: the address of a
>   two dimensional array of type `int`, the number of rows in the array,
>   and the number of columns in the array. Have the function calculate
>   the sum of the squares of the elements.

For example, for the array of `nums` that is pictured below:

```
  23  12  14   3

  31  25  41  17
```

the call of the function might be `sumsquares ( nums, 2, 4 )`; and the value returned would be `4434`. Write a short program to test your function.

---

So far my program consists of:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int addarrayA(int arrayA[],int highestvalueA);

int addarrayA(int arrayA[],int highestvalueA)
{
int sum=0, i;
for (i=1; i<highestvalueA; i++)
    sum = (i*i);

return sum;
}

int main( void )
{
int arr [2][4] = {{ 23, 12, 14,  3 },
                 { 31, 25, 41, 17 }};

printf( "The sum of the squares: %d. \n", addarrayA (arr[2], arr[4]) );

return 0;
}
```

The answer I am receiving is a huge negative number but it should be 4434.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Which huge negative number?

Comment: You do not pass a 2D array and your functios don't take one either.

Comment: You don't use the `arrayA` parameter in your function, which I imagine would be something you should be doing.

Comment: I think before asking for help you should try to convince yourself of why your code should work. (Hint: it really doesn't even come close to your description of things.)

Comment: Hint: *"the call of the function might be `sumsquares( nums, 2, 4 );`"*

Comment: in your addarrayA(arr[2], arr[4]), you're running out of range. thus you're running into unknown memory location. the values in these locations are random.  in C/C++ you need to be careful of memory locations and the range of your arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned in question, you need `sumsquares( array, 2, 4 );` , but your function don't do that.

See below code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int sumsquares(int* arrayA,int row, int column);

int sumsquares(int* arrayA,int row, int column)
{
    int sum=0, i;
    for (i=0; i<row*column; i++)
        sum += (arrayA[i]*arrayA[i]);

    return sum;
}

int main( void )
{
    int arr [2][4] = {{ 23, 12, 14,  3 },
                      { 31, 25, 41, 17 }};

    printf( "The sum of the squares: %d. \n", sumsquares (&arr[0][0], 2, 4) );

    return 0;
}
```

> **Output**:
>
> ```
> The sum of the squares: 4434.
> ```

Comment: Ah, I see. THANK YOU!!

Answer (score -2):

We might use this syntax to create a multi-dimensional array in C:

```
arr = (int **) malloc (( n *sizeof(int *));
```